# Duplicate keys print in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, duplicates, iteration

I made a 'dictionary of lists' object and key is in string format. I accessed 10 documents and used each unique term(word) as my key and saved it in a list. i.e.`word_tokens["abc"] = ["1:4","5:2","8:5"]` that means word = "abc" occur 4 times in document 1, 2 times in document 5 and 5 times in document 8.

my code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


stop_words_file = open("englishST.txt",'r')

stop_words = []
for st in stop_words_file:
    st = st.strip()
    stop_words.append(st)

stop_words_file.close()


fileName = "docs-1/doc-"
word_tokens = {}          //dictionary object
cnt = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    file_name = fileName + str(i)

    file = open(file_name,'r')

    for sentence in file:
        word = []
        word = word_tokenize(sentence)
        for w in word:
            w = w.lower()
            if w not in stop_words:

                if word_tokens.get(w) == None:
                    dummy = []
                    dummy.append(str(i)+":1")
                    word_tokens[w] = dummy
                else:
                    dummy = []
                    dummy = word_tokens[w]
                    tempStr = dummy[-1]
                    temp = tempStr.split(':')
                    if temp[0] == str(i):
                        temp[1] = str(int(temp[1])+1)
                        dummy[-1] = temp[0]+':'+temp[1]
                        word_tokens[w] = dummy
                    else:  
                        dummy = word_tokens[w]
                        dummy.append(str(i)+":1")
                        word_tokens[w] = dummy
                 cnt = cnt+1

    file.close()
    if len(word_tokens) != 0:
        print(dict_count)
        fname = dictFileName + str(dict_count)
        f = open(fname, "w+")
        f.write(str(word_tokens))
        f.close()

    j = 1
    for key,val in word_tokens.items():
        print(j,key,val)
        j = j + 1


   print(word_tokens)
```

while directly printing the dictionary no multiple keys with same values are there but when iterating over the dictionary using for loop I get multiple keys(i.e same key occuring more than once) and I have to remove duplicate keys and append all values for duplicate keys into a single key.

while writing `print(word_tokens)`

```
{'neurobeachin': ['1:1'], '(': ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1'], 'nbea': ['1:6'], ')': ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1'], 'regulates': ['1:1'], 'neuronal': ['1:1'], 'membrane': ['1:1'], 'protein': ['1:1', '8:2'], 'trafficking': ['1:1'], 'required': ['1:1'], 'development': ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2'],...... }
```

while writing this `for key,val in word_tokens.items():`

```
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5']
.....
102 obesity ['1:1']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7']
......
220 investigation ['2:1']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3']
......
296 products ['3:1']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19']
...............
```

i want to iterate each (key, value) pair but it gives me answer like above, can somebody suggest the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with the `nltk` library. However, the reason I think you are seeing "*duplicates*" is because your `for key,val in word_tokens.items()` is nested under `for i in range(1,10)`.

Have you tried moving the `for key,val in word_tokens.items()` from inside to outside?

The below code blocks are fairly large but done so to demonstrate why I think you are encountering your problem. Beyond the fixing of the nested loop, you should also strive to use `with open()` rather than `file.open()` for context management.

I took your dictionary `word_tokens` and simply performed your code (without parsing tokens of course) and achieved the result you were looking for:

```
>>> word_tokens = {'neurobeachin': ['1:1'], '(': ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1'], 'nbea': ['1:6'], ')': ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1'], 'regulates': ['1:1'], 'neuronal': ['1:1'], 'membrane': ['1:1'], 'protein': ['1:1', '8:2'], 'trafficking': ['1:1'], 'required': ['1:1'], 'development': ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']}
>>> j = 1
>>> for key, value in word_tokens.items():
        print (j, key, value)
        j = j + 1


1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
>>>
```

Now to test my hypothesis (somewhat...since the dictionary would technically be *growing* while looping within the nested loop):

```
>>> for _ in range(1, 10):
        j = 1
        for key, value in word_tokens.items():
            print (j, key, value)
            j = j + 1


1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
1 neurobeachin ['1:1']
2 ( ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
3 nbea ['1:6']
4 ) ['1:5', '2:7', '3:3', '4:19', '5:5', '7:1', '8:2', '9:1']
5 regulates ['1:1']
6 neuronal ['1:1']
7 membrane ['1:1']
8 protein ['1:1', '8:2']
9 trafficking ['1:1']
10 required ['1:1']
11 development ['1:1', '2:1', '6:1', '7:1', '9:2']
>>>
```